# function '<-'/2 undefined Error in receive block Elixir

Tags: elixir

This is my Elixir code.

```
defmodule ErlProcess do
    def receiver do
        receive do
            {:sayHello, msg}->sender<-{:ok, "ok"}
        end
    end
end
```

But it gives this error.

```
** (CompileError) spawn.exs:4: function '<-'/2 undefined
    (stdlib) lists.erl:1323: :lists.foreach/2
    (stdlib) erl_eval.erl:569: :erl_eval.do_apply/6
    (elixir) src/elixir.erl:140: :elixir.eval_forms/4
    (elixir) src/elixir_lexical.erl:17: :elixir_lexical.run/2
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`pid <- msg` was removed, please `send pid, msg` instead.