# (UndefinedFunctionError) undefined function change/2 in Model

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I run some code with `iex -S mix`

This is ok:

```
user = Repo.get User, 1

Ecto.Changeset.change user, %{name: "xxxx"}
```

but this is wrong:

```
User.change user, %{name: "xxxx"}
```

raise `(UndefinedFunctionError) undefined function Rumbl.User.change/2`

I notice there is `import Ecto.Changeset` in function model in file web.ex

```
def model do
  quote do
    use Ecto.Schema

    import Ecto
    import Ecto.Changeset
    import Ecto.Query, only: [from: 1, from: 2]
  end
end
```

So I think User.change/2 should works as same as Ecto.Changeset.change/2, is it right?

Comment: does your User model have use AppName.Web, :model?

Comment: @SashaFonseca I have, It's Rumbl from the book "programming phoenix"

Comment: Please see your answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22587524/function-2-undefined-error-in-receive-block-elixir

Comment: @alecs.popa, I think it's different problem, i am misunderstanding the `import`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you may be misunderstanding how `import` works.

From [the docs](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/v1.2/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#import/2):

> Imports functions and macros from other modules.
>
> import allows one to easily access functions or macros from others modules without using the qualified name.

What this means is that you don't have to use `Ecto.Changeset.change(user, %{}` inside of the module, you can instead do `change(user, %{})`.

This change only imports the functions to the module being used. It does not define them as functions on the model that is imported into.

If you are in iex and don't want to type out the fully qualified function name, you can either do:

```
alias Ecto.Changeset
Changeset.change(user, %{})
```

or:

```
import Ecto.Changeset
change(user, %{})
```

Comment: Thanks, i really misunderstand `import`, It's different with ruby's include.